# How to simplify this expressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How to simplify this expression:
\begin{equation}
f(x, n) = x^{(n)} - x^{(n-1)} - .... x^{(n-n)}
\end{equation}
I don't need the final answer, just some clue for approach I can use.
And this is the complete expression I want to calculate:
\begin{equation}
x . (f(x-1, n)-1)
\end{equation}

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"? `HornerForm`? `Factor`ed? Can you give more details? Is this actually a *Mathematica* question and not just a [math.se] question? If so, can you enter your functions in proper *Mathematica* syntax, properly formatted in code blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Define the function f[x,n] as

```
f[x_, n_] := FullSimplify[x^n - Sum[x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}]]

(1 + (-2 + x) x^n)/(-1 + x)
```

Now calculate the expression:

```
x (f[x - 1, n] - 1) // FullSimplify

((-1 + (-1 + x)^n) (-3 + x) x)/(-2 + x)
```

Comment: If you define `f` with `SetDelayed` you should use `Evaluate`: `f[x_, n_] := Evaluate@FullSimplify[x^n - Sum[x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}]]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon -- I'm not sure I understand the purpose of the `Evaluate`.

Comment: -`Clear[f]` evaluate its definition and look at the saved definition of `f` using `?f` without the `Evaluate` then with its use. `Evaluate` avoids repeated calculation of the closed form of the `Sum`.